# How to return a file using an AJAX request

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I use the following ajax call to send some data over to a PHP page, which generates an excel file.  If I run the PHP page by itself with fake data already ascribed to an array, it downloads the file, but if I try to run the php page through the ajax button, nothing downloads.  I'm not sure what the issue is, but I'm getting a `500 Internal Server Error` as the php tries to send back the file.  See below:

**Request Headers:**

```
POST /XLS.php HTTP/1.1
Host: 127.0.0.1
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 15
Pragma: no-cache
Cache-Control: no-cache
Accept: */*
Origin: http://127.0.0.1
X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/40.0.2214.115 Safari/537.36
Content-Type: text/plain;charset=UTF-8
Referer: http://127.0.0.1/multiLine.php
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8,fr-FR;q=0.6,fr;q=0.4
Cookie: PHPSESSID=rd44cluc503datf36616b9e5b5; popupPartNumber=null
```

**Response Headers:**

```
HTTP/1.0 500 Internal Server Error
Date: Fri, 13 Mar 2015 18:21:55 GMT
Server: Apache/2.4.10 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.1i PHP/5.5.15
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.5.15
Content-disposition: attachment; filename="multiLine report 03.13.15 - .xlsx"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary
Cache-Control: must-revalidate
Pragma: public
Content-Length: 0
Connection: close
Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet
```

the ajax I'm using is:

```
$.ajax({
  url: "XLS.php", 
  type: "post",
  data: {xl: xl},
  }); //closes ajax call
```

and I've gone through about 7 different `contenttype:` options to see if one of those made the difference, but none of them did.

How do I get this file back?

Comment: It's an internal server error. Look at your server side code and your error logs. You can't tell what caused an internal server error from the client, it isn't a client error.

Answer (score 0):

If you're look to download a file using an ajax request you have two possibilities.

Fake it by redirecting the user to the download page and

As [skidadon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1634820/skidadon) pointedin comment instead of using POST parameter use GET parameter

```
 window.location = 'XLS.php?x1='+x1;
```

Or use the jquery.fileDownload library who perform an Ajax-like file download experience

https://github.com/johnculviner/jquery.fileDownload

Comment: I think I like where you're going with this.  Plus you can send "$_GET" parameters to the download.php script to tell it what to download.  John Wu, get started on this one sir.

Comment: @skidadon yeah you're totally right just added it. Thanks :)

Comment: Thank you two.  There's no specific reason why I need to use ajax at all, if there's another way to do this.  It seems like something that is incredibly common on the internet... I just need to send an array of data to the php page, then have it download the file it generates....

Comment: @JohnWu You welcome it's a pleasure to help, did you achieved what you wanted given one of my solution ?

Comment: Well, I don't know how to `Fake it by redirecting the user to the download page`, so I'm reading up right now on the jquery.FileDownload library, (there's a lot of info there!)  I'll use this solution if it comes to it - just seems like a lot of work for something so simple, like there could be a much easier way for me to do all of this....

Comment: @JohnWu I just changed my code to make it reflect more your's. In fact you just need to change the POST variable that you have in your php file by get, for example if you have one variable name `$_POST['x1']` change it to `$_GET['x1']`. When you done this replace the javascript lines that you've put in you're answer by the one that I gave you. It should all Work :)

Answer (score 0):

This is not posible using ajax (xrh request).

Never an AJAX request will download a file to the user PC.

The solution is make and invisible iframe and post a form to it, then the browser will respect your header indicating the download.

Sorry for not having at this time an example for you, but hope to have addressed your work in the right direction and thus avoid waste more time testing.